# Display Shipping address2 in a text on WooCommerce email notifications

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, orders, email-notifications

In the WooCommerce checkout field `shipping_address_2`, I have established a custom discount coupon. What I need is to get this order field value in a specific email notification.

Here is my code attempt:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_content_to_specific_email', 20, 4 );
function add_content_to_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    if ( $email->id == 'customer_processing_order' ) {
        echo '<h2 class="email-upsell-title">Get 20% off</h2><p class="email-upsell-p">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>  get_post_meta( $order_id, '_shipping_address_2', true ) </strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
    }
}
```

It doesn't works. What I want to transform this field value into a string  between `<strong>` html tags.

Your help is welcome please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You were very near to  get what you were expecting. The correct was instead:

```
echo '<h2 class="email-upsell-title">Get 20% off</h2><p class="email-upsell-p">Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code "<strong>' .  get_post_meta( $order->ger_id(), '_shipping_address_2', true ) . '</strong>" to receive a 20% discount on your next purchase! Click here to continue shopping.</p>';
```

> But it's better to use `WC_Order` `get_shipping_address_2()` method.

Here is your revisited code:

```
add_action( 'woocommerce_email_before_order_table', 'add_content_to_specific_email', 20, 4 );
function add_content_to_specific_email( $order, $sent_to_admin, $plain_text, $email ) {
    // For customer processing and completed orders notifications
    if ( in_array($email->id, ['customer_processing_order', 'customer_completed_order']) ) {
        if( $coupon_code = $order->get_shipping_address_2() ) {
            echo '<h2 class="email-upsell-title">'.__("Get 20% off").'</h2>
            <p class="email-upsell-p">';
            printf(
                __("Thank you for making this purchase! Come back and use the code %s to receive a 20%% discount on your next purchase! %s."),
                '"<strong>'.$coupon_code.'</strong>"',
                '<a href="'. get_permalink( wc_get_page_id( 'shop' ) ) .'">' . __("Click here to continue shopping") . '</a>'
            );
            echo '</p>';
        }
    }
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or active theme). It should works.

Comment: Cool!! Many thanks!! So much better !! Could you also add it to the same function "if ( $email->id == 'customer_completed_order' ) {}"
 in the completed order mail?

Comment: @Carlos Claro! Code updated, to handle customer processing **and completed** orders notifications

Comment: Good morning, I tried the code and I get this error: Syntax error, unexpected T_IF on line 5 if ($ coupon_code = $ order-> get_shipping_address_2 ()) {

Comment: @CarlosGomez Updated… Sorry, that was a missing closing round bracket in the first IF statement (on line 5)

Comment: Thank you!  I need to leave only the text in the mail if the field of shipping_address_2 is not empty, could you help me?

Comment: Normally you will use `if( $order->get_ shipping_address_2() ) { // Display the text }` but it may not work as WooCommerce may copy the billing fields to shipping fields. In that case, ask a new question and notify me here.